# Part of function inside a variable error

Tags: javascript

Sup guys,
So, i'm trying to reduce my code to avoid redundance and i'm stuck on it;
i know yet that you can reduce some code for example:
    var alert=**console.warn**;alert('sup!');

But on my code i have other context:
i'm putting a part of a function, resumed like it:
    var alert=console.warn**(**;
how can i call the same example above to show the alert?
i'm getting always error

If u get the simple example, i will go harder:
i've this partial code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
var option = options[i];
var optionText = option.text;
var lowerOptionText = optionText.toLowerCase();
var lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp("^" + text, "i");
var match = optionText.match(regex);
var contains = lowerOptionText.indexOf(lowerText) != -1;
if (match || contains) {
```

and i want to put it on a variable

After it, i want to call the variable and merge with  this code:

```
}
searchBox.selectedIndex = 0;    
}  //CloseForFunction
```

Plz help me.
Thanks

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're assuming functions are the same thing as text.  They are not interchangeable.  You may want to look into writing functions with arguments.

Comment: On top of what Daniel said, alert is a built in function, you should never use built in functions as variable names.

Comment: Thank u guys for answer.
I think i got it so there isnt a way to call a unfinished code? If u have to call a partial code like “for(){“, you is forced to use all the next part until the “}”?